# How can I convert a Shard mongo cluster to a Replica Set mongo cluster? real-time migrations

Tags: mongodb

I have a shard mongo cluster(shard node has no replica set), and some applications are using it, I want to real-time migrations to a replica set mongo cluster. Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, a standalone node is a single mongod, a replica set is several nodes joined together, and a sharded cluster is several replica sets joined together.  Are you trying to go from a standalone to a replica set or from a sharded cluster to a replica set?

Comment: @Joe I have two mongo cluster, one is shard mode, another is replica set mode. I wan to   real-time sync data from sharded cluster to replica set cluster.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-sharded-cluster-to-replica-set/

Comment: @Oleg Mongodump and mongorestore require the application to suspend service for a period of time

Comment: You are going to need to restart all applications anyway, once a driver discovers topology it won't accept nodes of other types (sharded vs replica set).